# Spring Boot POSTed JSON data validation

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have controller for post request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/projects/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String addProject(@Valid @RequestBody usersProjects project, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Error ::: " +result.toString());
    }

    logger.info(project.toString());

    usersProjects.addProject(project);

    return "ok";
}
```

Entity for database table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_projects")
public class UsersProjects {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    private Boolean approved;

    @NotEmpty
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> spaces;
    @NotEmpty
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> owners;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
             fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UsersProjectJobs> jobs;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
             fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<UsersProjectData> data;


    public UsersProjects() {

    }

    public UsersProjects(String name, List<String> spaces, List<String> owners) {
        this.name = name;
        this.spaces = spaces;
        this.owners = owners;
        this.approved = false;
    }

    public Boolean getApproved() {
        return approved;
    }
    public void setApproved(Boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to POST data to server with CURL:

```
curl -i  -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Accept:application/json"  -X POST -d '{ "name": "123", "spaces": ["123"], "owners": ["123"]}' http://localhost:8080/projects/add
```

And got error:

The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

I have found a lot of topic where described that this error occurs when Spring can't validate received JSON data. What I should add to log4j.properties for more verbose output or maybe someone knows link to good topic about model validation?

Thank you.

**UPD** log4j configuration:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.context=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.http=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.springframework.web=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.category.org.springframework.beans.factory=DEBUG, stdout

log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.core=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.catalina.session=DEBUG

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**UPD UPD**:

```
public class validatorAddProject {
    private String name;
    private List<String> spaces;
    private List<String> owners;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<String> getSpaces() {
        return spaces;
    }
    public void setSpaces(List<String> spaces) {
        this.spaces = spaces;
    }
    public List<String> getOwners() {
        return owners;
    }
    public void setOwners(List<String> owners) {
        this.owners = owners;
    }
}


@RequestMapping(value="/projects/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String addProject(@Valid @RequestBody validatorAddProject form, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("Error ::: " +result.toString());
    }

    usersProjects project = new usersProjects(form.getName(), form.getSpaces(), form.getOwners());
    usersProjects.addProject(project);

    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Is that the full `UsersProjects` class? Is that a type in the handler method? Turn your logs to DEBUG and look again.

Comment: My log4j.properties file: http://pastebin.com/6KuuYT61 I don't see here any records about validation errors. Yes, it's full entity class.

Comment: Your logs should contain information about why you got a 400. Check them. If they don't, your logger is misconfigured.

Comment: @AlexanderGryanko Please add your log4j.properties to the post, don't let people follow a link to get all the information.

Comment: If that is your full class you are missing some getters/setters so no binding will be done. Unless you configured Jackson to do field based binding, by default it does property (get/set) binding.

Comment: public String addProject(@Valid @RequestBody usersProjects project, BindingResult result) -> userProjects class Should it be capitalized ?

Comment: @M.Deinum as I understand I need add setters and getters for fields wich will be received in json post request. Jackson don't use class constructor for binding. Is it right?

Comment: Correct. You could make jackson use the construct but that would involve a lot of configuration and custom mappers.

Answer (score 1):

there is a nice [project](https://github.com/jirutka/spring-rest-exception-handler) that shows how to handle e.g. validation errors.
Just have a look at the [MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionHandler](https://github.com/jirutka/spring-rest-exception-handler/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/jirutka/spring/exhandler/handlers/MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionHandler.java)

Comment: Thank you, but its not what I want. I've found solution by adding slf4j to project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add setters or decorate your constructor with `@JsonCreator`. Also upgrading to the latest Boot version, if you are using that (I'm guessing from the tags), should expose the `BindingException` in the response if that's what it is.

Comment: Thank you. I have added JsonCreator and JsonProperty to the Entity class, it works but not like I want. I've created another one public class only with fields what I want to add to database.